How to automatically block an IP address on apache (on Windows)?
I've tried various combinations of mod_evasive but every time I got different results of block hits.
IfModule mod_evasive20.c>
    DOSHashTableSize    1009
    DOSPageCount        10
    DOSSiteCount        10
    DOSPageInterval     60
    DOSSiteInterval     60
    DOSBlockingPeriod   60

    
    DOSLogDir           "/var/log/mod_evasive"
</IfModule>

I used this script to test:
ab -n 200 -c 1 http://localhost/api/

I want a solution on Windows.
